# How can i put condition in doctrine query builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have this query

```
$qb->select('u')
           ->from('UserBundle:User', 'u')
           ->where('u.location = :identifier')
           ->orderBy('u.firstName', 'ASC')
           ->setParameter('identifier', 2);
```

I want that if $identifier is present then it should filter the results otherwise i get all the results like

```
$qb->select('u')
               ->from('UserBundle:User', 'u')
                       if($identifier)             
                       ->where('u.location = :identifier')
               ->orderBy('u.firstName', 'ASC')
                       if($identifier) 
               ->setParameter('identifier', 2);
```

Is it possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible, you just have to restructure your code.

```
$qb->select('u')
           ->from('UserBundle:User', 'u')
           ->orderBy('u.firstName', 'ASC');
if($identifier) {
        $qb->where('u.location = :identifier')
           ->setParameter('identifier', 2);
}
```

Comment: isn't the orderby supposed to come in the end or it can come before where clause

Comment: That's the beauty of Query builder: Until `getQuery()` is called, you can modify the query in any order you like.